# FattureInCloud Create Invoice Document via API

Tags: php, flutter, rest, entity-framework, invoice

Hello everyone I have a problem, if I send the demo data from [https://developers.fattureincloud.it/docs/guides/invoice-creation#-create-the-document] the invoice being created but when I try to send my data the invoice not being create.

I pass the data from a Flutter app with this method:

```
Future<void> sendInvoice(
        BuildContext context,
        Quotation quotation,
        Quotation baseQuotation, {
        bool eInvoice = false,
      }) async {
        try {
          double vatPercentage =
              double.parse(baseQuotation.vatPercentage!.replaceAll('%', ''));
          DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd');
          double totalPrice = 0.0;
          double totalVat = 0.0;
          Map<String, dynamic> entity = <String, dynamic>{};
          List<Map<String, dynamic>> itemsList = <Map<String, dynamic>>[];
          List<Map<String, Object>> paymentsList = [];
    
          entity = {
            "id": int.parse(baseQuotation.userId!),
            "name": capitalizeEveryFirstLetter(quotation.userInvoiceName!),
            "vat_number": quotation.userInvoiceVat,
            "tax_code": quotation.userInvoiceCf,
            "address_street": quotation.userInvoiceAddress,
            "address_postal_code": quotation.userInvoiceCap,
            "address_city": quotation.userInvoiceCity,
            "address_province": quotation.userInvoiceProvince,
            "country": capitalizeEveryFirstLetter(quotation.userInvoiceCountry!),
            "certified_email": quotation.userInvoicePec,
            "ei_code": quotation.userInvoiceSdi
          };
    
          if (baseQuotation.visits!.isNotEmpty) {
            for (var visit in baseQuotation.visits!.split(',')) {
              var visitFields = visit.split('§');
              var name = visitFields.isNotEmpty ? visitFields[0] : '';
              var netPrice =
                  visitFields.length > 2 ? double.parse(visitFields[2]) : 0.0;
              var vatPrice = netPrice / 100 * vatPercentage;
    
              itemsList.add({
                "name": capitalizeEveryFirstLetter(name),
                "net_price": netPrice,
                "gross_price":
                    vatPercentage != 0 ? (netPrice + vatPrice) : netPrice,
                "vat": {
                  "id": 3,
                  "value": vatPercentage,
                }
              });
    
              totalPrice += netPrice;
              totalVat += vatPrice;
            }
          } else {
            var netPrice = double.parse(baseQuotation.cost!);
            var vatPrice = netPrice / 100 * vatPercentage;
    
            itemsList.add({
              "name": capitalizeEveryFirstLetter(baseQuotation.requestType!),
              "net_price": netPrice,
              "gross_price": vatPercentage != 0 ? (netPrice + vatPrice) : netPrice,
              "vat": {
                "id": vatPercentage == 0 ? 6 : 54,
                "value": vatPercentage,
              }
            });
    
            totalPrice = netPrice;
            totalVat = vatPrice;
          }
    
          paymentsList = [
            {
              "amount": vatPercentage != 0 ? (totalPrice + totalVat) : totalPrice,
              "due_date":
                  dateFormat.format(DateTime.now().add(const Duration(days: 30))),
              "status": "not_paid",
            }
          ];
    
          var body = json.encode({
            'send_invoice': 'send_invoice',
            "data": {
              "type": "invoice",
              "amount_net": totalPrice,
              "amount_vat": vatPercentage != 0 ? totalVat : 0,
              "entity": entity,
              "date": dateFormat.format(DateTime.now()),
              "number": 1,
              "items_list": itemsList,
              "payments_list": paymentsList,
              "e_invoice": eInvoice == false ? false : true,
            },
          });
    
          final response = await AppConst().client.post(
                Uri.parse(AppConst.invoice).replace(host: AppConst.domain),
                body: body,
              );
    
          if (response.statusCode == 200 || response.statusCode == 201) {
            print('Response_body: ${response.body}');
            print('Body: $body');
    
            await Alerts.successAlert(
              context,
              title: 'Riuscito',
              subtitle: 'Fattura emessa',
            );
          } else {
            print('Can\'t send Invoice');
          }
        } catch (error) {
          print('ERROR_sendInvoice: $error');
        } finally {
          AppConst().client.close();
          await context.read<StateProvider>().buildFuture(context);
        }
      }
```

to this PHP code:

```
<?php
use FattureInCloud\Model\Currency;
use FattureInCloud\Model\DocumentTemplate;
use FattureInCloud\Model\Entity;
use FattureInCloud\Model\IssuedDocument;
use FattureInCloud\Model\IssuedDocumentItemsListItem;
use FattureInCloud\Model\IssuedDocumentPaymentsListItem;
use FattureInCloud\Model\IssuedDocumentStatus;
use FattureInCloud\Model\IssuedDocumentType;
use FattureInCloud\Model\CreateIssuedDocumentRequest;
use FattureInCloud\Model\Language;
use FattureInCloud\Model\PaymentAccount;
use FattureInCloud\Model\PaymentMethod;
use FattureInCloud\Model\VatType;

if (isset($_POST['send_invoice'])) {
  require_once(__DIR__ . '/../../../conn/config.php');

  require_once(__DIR__ . '/../../../plugins/fattureincloud/lib/Api/IssuedDocumentsApi.php');

  require_once(__DIR__ . '/../../../plugins/fattureincloud/lib/ApiException.php');
  require_once(__DIR__ . '/../../../plugins/fattureincloud/lib/Configuration.php');
  require_once(__DIR__ . '/../../../plugins/fattureincloud/lib/HeaderSelector.php');
  require_once(__DIR__ . '/../../../plugins/fattureincloud/lib/ObjectSerializer.php');

  require_once(__DIR__ . '/../../../plugins/fattureincloud/lib/Model/Currency.php');
  require_once(__DIR__ . '/../../../plugins/fattureincloud/lib/Model/DocumentTemplate.php');
  require_once(__DIR__ . '/../../../plugins/fattureincloud/lib/Model/Entity.php');
  require_once(__DIR__ . '/../../../plugins/fattureincloud/lib/Model/IssuedDocument.php');
  require_once(__DIR__ . '/../../../plugins/fattureincloud/lib/Model/IssuedDocumentItemsListItem.php');
  require_once(__DIR__ . '/../../../plugins/fattureincloud/lib/Model/IssuedDocumentPaymentsListItem.php');
  require_once(__DIR__ . '/../../../plugins/fattureincloud/lib/Model/IssuedDocumentStatus.php');
  require_once(__DIR__ . '/../../../plugins/fattureincloud/lib/Model/IssuedDocumentType.php');
  require_once(__DIR__ . '/../../../plugins/fattureincloud/lib/Model/CreateIssuedDocumentRequest.php');
  require_once(__DIR__ . '/../../../plugins/fattureincloud/lib/Model/Language.php');
  require_once(__DIR__ . '/../../../plugins/fattureincloud/lib/Model/PaymentAccount.php');
  require_once(__DIR__ . '/../../../plugins/fattureincloud/lib/Model/PaymentMethod.php');
  require_once(__DIR__ . '/../../../plugins/fattureincloud/lib/Model/VatType.php');

  $config = FattureInCloud\Configuration::getDefaultConfiguration()->setAccessToken(FATTURE_IN_CLOUD_TOKEN_KEY);

  $apiInstance = new FattureInCloud\Api\IssuedDocumentsApi(
    new GuzzleHttp\Client(),
    $config
  );

  $postData = json_decode($_POST['data'], true);

$type = $postData['data']['type'];
  $amount_net = floatval($postData['data']['amount_net']);
  $amount_vat = floatval($postData['data']['amount_vat']);

  $entity_id = intval($postData['data']['entity']['id']);
  $entity_name = $postData['data']['entity']['name'];
  $entity_vat_number = $postData['data']['entity']['vat_number'];
  $entity_tax_code = $postData['data']['entity']['tax_code'];
  $entity_address_street = $postData['data']['entity']['address_street'];
  $entity_address_postal_code = $postData['data']['entity']['address_postal_code'];
  $entity_address_city = $postData['data']['entity']['address_city'];
  $entity_address_province = $postData['data']['entity']['address_province'];
  $entity_country = $postData['data']['entity']['country'];
  $entity_certified_email = $postData['data']['entity']['certified_email'];
  $entity_ei_code = $postData['data']['entity']['ei_code'];

  $date = $postData['data']['date'];
  $number = intval($postData['data']['number']);

  $items_list = $postData['data']['items_list'];
  $payments_list = $postData['data']['payments_list'];
  $e_invoice = $postData['data']['e_invoice'] == 'true' ? true : false;

  $entity = new Entity;
  $entity
  ->setId($entity_id)
  ->setName($entity_name)
  ->setVatNumber($entity_vat_number)
  ->setTaxCode($entity_tax_code)
  ->setAddressStreet($entity_address_street)
  ->setAddressPostalCode($entity_address_postal_code)
  ->setAddressCity($entity_address_city)
  ->setAddressProvince($entity_address_province)
  ->setCountry($entity_country)
  ->setCertifiedEmail($entity_certified_email)
  ->setEInvoice($e_invoice);

  $invoice = new IssuedDocument;
  $invoice->setType($type == 'invoice' ? IssuedDocumentType::INVOICE : IssuedDocumentType::PROFORMA);
  // $invoice->setAmountNet($amount_net);
  // $invoice->setAmountVat($amount_vat);
  $invoice->setEntity($entity);
  $invoice->setDate(new DateTime($date));
  $invoice->setNumber($number);

  $itemsList = array();
  foreach ($items_list as $itemData) {
    $vatData = $itemData['vat'];
    $item = new IssuedDocumentItemsListItem(
      array(
        "name" => $itemData['name'],
        "net_price" => floatval($itemData['net_price']),
        "gross_price" => floatval($itemData['gross_price']),
        "vat" => new VatType(
          array(
            "id" => intval($vatData['id']),
            "value" => intval($vatData['value'])
          )
        )
      )
    );
    $itemsList[] = $item;
  }
  $invoice->setItemsList($itemsList);

  $paymentsList = array();
  foreach ($payments_list as $paymentData) {
    $status = $paymentData['status'] === 'paid' ? IssuedDocumentStatus::PAID : IssuedDocumentStatus::NOT_PAID;
    $item = new IssuedDocumentPaymentsListItem(
      array(
        "amount" => floatval($paymentData['amount']),
        "due_date" => new DateTime($paymentData['due_date']),
        "status" => $status
      )
    );
    $paymentsList[] = $item;
  }
  $invoice->setPaymentsList($paymentsList);

  $invoice->setEInvoice($e_invoice);

  $create_issued_document_request = new CreateIssuedDocumentRequest;
  $create_issued_document_request->setData($invoice);

        try {
          $result = $apiInstance->createIssuedDocument(FATTURE_IN_CLOUD_COMPANY_ID, $create_issued_document_request);
          print_r($result);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
          echo 'Exception when calling IssuedDocumentsApi->createIssuedDocument: ', $e->getMessage(), PHP_EOL;
        }
      }
      ?>
```

The json I should send is as follows:

```
{"send_invoice":"send_invoice","data":{"type":"invoice","amount_net":369,"amount_vat":18.45,"entity":{"id":1,"name":"Jfhgdbvnm","vat_number":"dfgbvnm","tax_code":",kj","address_street":"nghjf","address_postal_code":"vbnm,","address_city":"fdvb","address_province":"vbngh","country":"Italia","certified_email":"vbnmjh.gh","ei_code":"ghjf"},"date":"2023-09-06","number":1,"items_list":[{"name":"Taxi Sanitario","net_price":369,"gross_price":387.45,"vat":{"id":54,"value":5}}],"payments_list":[{"amount":387.45,"due_date":"2023-10-06","status":"not_paid"}],"e_invoice":false}}
```